# Trying to connect to Amazon EC2 through Java w/ keypair

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, public-key

I'm trying to connect to an instance of Amazon's EC2 cloud using a Keypair and I've been having a good amount of trouble.  Ultimately I want to be able to transfer a file from my local machine to the cloud but I still need to get connected first.  Here's what I have now:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, UserAuthException {
    SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient();
    ssh.addHostKeyVerifier("2a:a5:fe:10:51:2c:e0:de:2e:99:cc:a4:7d:43:01:0f");
    ssh.connect("address for cloud instance");
    try {
        ssh.authPublickey("ec2-user", "C:\\Users\\Pat\\Desktop\\public_key.pem");
        final String src = "C:\\Users\\Pat\\Desktop\\test file.txt";
        ssh.newSCPFileTransfer().upload(new FileSystemFile(src), "/home/ec2-user/");
    } finally {
        ssh.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Before, I have run this without the addHostKeyVerifier line and it gives me an error saying that it couldn't load ssh-rsa key with the fingerprint that is now in that command.  The strange thing is that the amazon account shows a different fingerprint for this keypair, could that have anything to do with this?  When I run the above code I get this error:

```
[main] INFO net.schmizz.sshj.common.SecurityUtils - BouncyCastle registration succeeded
[main] WARN net.schmizz.sshj.DefaultConfig - Disabling high-strength ciphers: cipher strengths     apparently limited by JCE policy
[main] INFO net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl - Client identity string: SSH-2.0-    SSHJ_0_8_1_SNAPSHOT
[main] INFO net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl - Server identity string: SSH-2.0-    OpenSSH_6.2
[main] INFO net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl - Disconnected - BY_APPLICATION
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org/bouncycastle/openssl/EncryptionException
    at net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.keyprovider.PKCS8KeyFile$Factory.create(PKCS8KeyFile.java:45)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.keyprovider.PKCS8KeyFile$Factory.create(PKCS8KeyFile.java:40)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.common.Factory$Named$Util.create(Factory.java:74)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.loadKeys(SSHClient.java:479)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.loadKeys(SSHClient.java:438)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.authPublickey(SSHClient.java:349)
    at scpupload.SCPUpload.main(SCPUpload.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.openssl.EncryptionException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

any and all help is appreciated

Comment: Put the bouncy castle libraries into your classpath.

Comment: They are in the classpath, I have them set as compile-time libraries

Comment: Hmmm. Something must not be right though, to @Seelenvirtuose 's point. You shouldn't be getting the NoClassDefFoundError if those are on the classpath. Any idea why those are showing up?

Comment: Not sure, I downloaded the other bouncycastle libraries and added those as well and now I'm getting an error that the PEMReader class can't be found

Comment: The two bouncy castle libraries I have to get past java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/openssl/EncryptionException are bcpkix-jdk15on-1.53.jar and bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.53.jar I got them from [here](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/)